# Inserir imagem base de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Boas amigos, estou com um pequeno problema na inserção de imagem na base de dados

```
function apresenta_formulario() {
    if (isset($_GET['id_publicidade'])){

    $ligacao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "publicidades");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Erro na liga��o MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql = "select * from publicidade where id_publicidade = '" . $_GET['id_publicidade'] . "'";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql);

    $registo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

    $descricao=$registo['descricao'];

    ?>
    <form  name="upload_imagem" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <p>Alterar Publicidade nº <?php echo $_GET["id_publicidade"]; ?> </p>
        <p>Nome da publicidade <input type="text" name="nome" size="50" value="<?php echo $registo["nome"]; ?>"></p>
        <label for="file">Ficheiro:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <br>
        <p>Categoria <input type="text" name="categoria" size="50" value="<?php echo $registo["categoria"]; ?>"></p>
        <p>Visualizações <input type="text" name="visualizacoes" size="50" value="<?php echo $registo["visualizacoes"]; ?>"></p>
        <p>Estado <input type="text" name="estado" size="50" value="<?php echo $registo["estado"]; ?>"></p>
        <p>Coordenada X <br><input type="text" name="x" size="50" id="CorX" value="<?php echo $registo["x"]; ?>"></p>
        <p>Coordenada Y <br><input type="text" name="y" size="50" id="CorY" value="<?php echo $registo["y"]; ?>"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="alterar"></p>
        <p> <input type="reset" name="reset"></p>
        <input name="id_publicidade" value="<?php echo $_GET["id_publicidade"]; ?>" type="hidden">
    </form>
    <p id="registo" style="height: 400px"></p>
    <?php
    mysqli_close($ligacao);

    }
    else{
    header("Location: listar.php");
    }
}

// fun��o respons�vel pelo processamento do formul�rio (tudo c�gido PHP)
function processa_formulario() {
    define ("MAX_SIZE","1000");

//Função que devolve a extensão de um ficheiro
function getExtension($str) 
{
    $i = strrpos($str,".");
    if (!$i) 
    { 
        return ""; 
    }
    $l = strlen($str) - $i;
    $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
    return $ext;
}

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $categoria=$_POST['categoria'];
    $visualizacoes = $_POST['visualizacoes'];
    $estado=$_POST['estado'];
    $x=$_POST['x'];
    $y=$_POST['y'];
    $image = $_FILES['file']['name'];   
    $codigo = $_POST["id_publicidade"];
    //Verifica se existe alguma imagem para ser importada
    if($image)//Existe uma imagem para ser importada
    {
       //Retira os elementos "/"
       $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);
       //Verifica qual a extensão do ficheiro
       $extension = getExtension($filename);
       //Coloca todos os caracteres da extensão com letra minuscula
       $extension = strtolower($extension);
      //Verifica os formatos de imagem que podem ser importados
      if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "gif"))//Formato diferente dos permitidos 
      {
          //print error message
           echo "<strong>Imagem:</strong> Este formato não pode ser importado! Utilize o formato jpg ou gif";
      }
      else//Formato permitido
      {
          //Verifica qual o tamanho da imagem seleccionada
          $size=filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
          //Verifica se o tamanho é superior a 100kb
          if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)//tamanho superior
          {
             echo 'A imagem não pode exceder o tamanho de '. MAX_SIZE .'kb';
          }
          else//tamanho inferior
          {
             //Gera um nome para a imagem
             $image_name=time().'.'.$extension;

             $img=$image_name;

             if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "imagens/".$image_name)) {

                $ligacao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","publicidades");
                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                    echo "Erro na ligação MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }
                echo $nome;
                $sql = "update publicidade set id_publicidade='".$codigo."', nome='".$nome."', descricao='".$image_name."', categoria='".$categoria."', estado='".$estado."', visualizacoes ='".$visualizacoes."', x= '".$x."' , y='".$y."' where id_publicidade = '".$codigo."' ";
                $resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql);

                if($resultado)
                {
                    $id_imagem = mysqli_insert_id($ligacao);
                    echo "Editado com sucesso";

                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Não foi possível efectuar o upload da imagem (nome para a base de dados)";
                }
             }
           }
       }
    }
    else//Não existe nenhuma imagem para ser importada 
    {
        $sql5 = "update publicidade set id_publicidade='".$codigo."', nome='".$nome."', estado='".$estado."', visualizacoes ='".$visualizacoes."', x= '".$x."' , y='".$y."' where id_publicidade = '".$codigo."' ";
                $resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql5);

    }
    mysqli_close($ligacao);
```

Bem pessoal o problema é o seguinte, se eu quiser alterar uma publicidade, se eu mudar a imagem e alterar os vários campos o programa funciona direito porem se o meu objetivo for apenas alterar os campos sem mexer na imagem o que acontece é que alem de criar registos repetidos na base de dados, ele não altera nada e não sei porque.

Comment: Tem certeza que você colocou seu código corretamente? tem uma função dentro da outra.